# Как использовать websocket в php

Tags: php, windows, websocket, openserver

Пытаюсь написать сервер, с использованием *websocket*. 
Работаю в *windows*. Использую *OpenServer*.

После поиска информации в *гугле*, прочитал некоторые статьи про то, как пользоваться *websocket-ами* в *php*. Многие из них упоминали *phpDaemon*, но, насколько я понял, в *windows* его использовать не получится. Также были статьи про то, как написать сервер с *websocket-ами* с нуля, но такое решение мне показалось черезчур сложным.

Есть ли способ легче? Возможно, есть библиотека для работы с сокетами?

Answer (score 1):

[Сокеты на PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sockets.php)

В Windows нормально работает.

Comment: В windows работает phpDaemon ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Вы вполне можете в винде запустить ваш деном как cli через терминал винды.
Достаточно установить php-cli и сделать что-то типа:

```
C:\PHP5\php-cli.exe -f <путь к файлу сервера>
```

да, и не забудьте в брандмауэре разрешить соответствующий порт